# Does light travel forever in a medium?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, fiber-optics

Light will travel forever in a vacuum. What about light in a medium? Does it travel forever too, but at a slower rate. Let’s say I run a fiber optic cable across the universe. I know it will travel slower in the cable, but will it eventually stop, or will it continue across the universe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even the best optical fiber has some attenuation. The very popular SMF-28 type, for example, has a maximum attenuation of 0.18 dB/km at 1550 nm, which is the optimum wavelength for attenuation.

That means that after a mere 1000 km, the power that entered the fiber will be reduced by 180 dB. If you started with 1 W, you'd have only an attowatt remaining. Whether you consider an arbitrarily large attenuation factor "stopped" or not is a semantic choice, but practically it means no receiver in the world could detect your signal after even 1000 km.

Most of the attenuation is due to absorption by impurities in the glass, like iron and hydroxide ions. So in principle you might be able to eliminate this and imagine a medium with much lower loss than optical fiber. But even then you'd have other issues to contend with such as the small attenuation due to the glass itself, scattering from the glass atoms, etc. You might be able to transmit across 1000 km, but not "across the universe".

Answer (score 1):

In a perfect, isotropic homogeneous etc. medium yes it will travel forever. In a real medium, like an actual fiber optic cable there will be imperfections which absorb and refract the light. Eventually all of the photons will have been absorbed and there won't be a light signal any more. The light hasn't "stopped", as such, it has transfered its energy to the molecules of the medium and ceased to exist as light. This is why real fiber optic systems need booster stations every few kilometers, they essentally "replace", the lost part of the photon signal.

Answer (score 0):

Lights never stop in mediums including optic cables. Or if you worry about energy dissipation, notice that energy of wave is relevant to its amplitude square (intensity or brightness for light), not phase velocity. 
Definitely, light will get weak when keep moving (gradually absorbed by medium), and when it is too dim to recognize, you could technically describe it as "vanished" or "stop propagating".